# Using \pgfmathifthenelse to place a node

Tags: tikz-pgf, ifthenelse

I'm trying to use the `\pgfmathifthenelse` command to place a node in my graph with `tikz`, but I'm continuing to have this error:

> "Incomplete \iffalse"

Here is my code :

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \def \n {4}
    \def \hradius {2cm}
    \def \vradius {1.2cm}
    \def \nradius {0cm}
    \def \lengths {3,4,6}
    \def \degree {3}
    \node (u) at (0,{2*\vradius}) {$\bullet$};
    \node (v) at (0,{-2*\vradius}) {$\bullet$};
    \node at (0,{2.2*\vradius}) {$u$};
    \node at (0,{-2.2*\vradius}) {$v$};
    \draw[>=latex] (v.center) -- (u.center) node [midway,left]{{$1$}};
    \foreach [count=\i, evaluate=\i as \k] \s in \lengths {
        \pgfmathparse{\s-1}
        \edef \l {\pgfmathresult}
        \pgfmathparse{\k-2}
        \def \xtmp {\pgfmathresult}
        \pgfmathparse{\xtmp+1}
        \edef \xfactor {\pgfmathresult}
        \pgfmathparse{\pgfmathifthenelse{\xtmp=0}{\xfactor {\xtmp}}\pgfmathresult
        \edef \xfinal {\pgfmathresult}
        \foreach \i in {1,...,\l}{
            \pgfmathparse{1/\s}
            \def \inverse {\pgfmathresult}
            \node (\s\i) at ({(\k-2)*\hradius},{((4*\vradius)*\inverse*\i)-2*\vradius}) {\k};
        }
    }

    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Does anybody know where the problem is?

Answer (score 2):

Some issues:

1. You were missing a bracket at the line with `pgfmathifthenelse`.
2. All your commands can be rewritten to set a variable inline instead of using `\pgfmathresult`. `\pgfmathparse` does that, but you can use `\pgfmathsetmacro<VARIABLE>{<CODE>}`

So, you can fix the `\pgfmathifthenelse` rewriting like this:

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\xfinal{(\xtmp==0?(\xfactor):\xtmp)}
```

which does

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\xfinal{(<TEST>?(<TRUE>):<FALSE>)}
```

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\n{4}
\def\hradius{2cm}
\def\vradius{1.2cm}
\def\nradius{0cm}
\def\lengths{3,4,6}
\def\degree{3}

\node (u) at (0,{2*\vradius}) {$\bullet$};
\node (v) at (0,{-2*\vradius}) {$\bullet$};
\node at (0,{2.2*\vradius}) {$u$};
\node at (0,{-2.2*\vradius}) {$v$};
\draw[>=latex] (v.center) -- (u.center) node [midway,left]{{$1$}};
\foreach [count=\i, evaluate=\i as \k] \s in \lengths {%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\l{\s-1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\xtmp{\k-2}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\xfactor{\xtmp+1}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\xfinal{(\xtmp==0?(\xfactor):\xtmp)}
    \foreach \i in {1,...,\l}{%
        \pgfmathsetmacro\inverse{1/\s}
        \node (\s\i) at ({(\k-2)*\hradius},{((4*\vradius)*\inverse*\i)-2*\vradius}) {\k};
    }
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```